# How do I output the files being copied in console?

Tags: powershell, logging, copy

I'm writing a PowerShell code to copy files in a folder to another folder. I want the console to display the files that are being copied, as well as the file size if possible.

Currently, I have tried using `-Verbose` But the output is not very readable.

I would like the console to display the files being copied, and the file size.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the parameter `-PassThru` for `Copy-Item`. But it will not show you the file size.

I would recommend you to use `robocopy.exe` for any copy jobs in powershell. It is more reilable and in your case it will show you the filesize.

Comment: Nice, but note that file size _is_ shown by default, in column `Length` - albeit as the unscaled, unformatted number of bytes.